# Knockout: multiple view models subscribe to Json

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I would like to be able to organize my Knockout code, like this:

- Import a 'Master Json' file and map it.
- Create multiple view models, which each reference particular sections of the 'Master Json' file.
- Bind all the observables in every view model to the values of the 'Master Json' file.

*Is it possible to use **ko.subscribable** to have everything subscribe to my json file as the master value?*

Or how can I move the $.getJSON (and save) functions from inside of each view model function?  Can I make a function so the getJSON results are re-usable in each of these view models?

```
function ApplesViewModel ( data ) {

    // ko.observables here 

    //Get Json
    $.getJSON("json/masterJson.json", function(allData) {
        var mappedSlides = $.map(allData, function(item) { return new Slide(item) });
        self.slides(mappedSlides);
    });    

    //Save Json
    self.save = function() {
        $.ajax("/masterJson", {
            data: ko.toJSON({ slides: self.slides }),
            type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(result) { alert(result) }
        });
    }; 
}

function BananasViewModel( data ) {
    //same as ApplesViewModel but with different observables
}

function CarrotsViewModel( data ) {
    //same as ApplesViewModel but with different observables
}

ko.applyBindings(new ApplesViewModel());
ko.applyBindings(new BananasViewModel());
ko.applyBindings(new CarrotsViewModel());
```

I don't want to import it many times because I think that will make a new copy each time.  It should only be one Json file.  When I try to move it, then I get errors that everything is undefined.

Maybe this is completely wrong approach.  Does everyone put everything all into one view model?  Won't it get confusing quickly?

Comment: It is rather unclear what you're asking tbh. Try to remove bits from your code that are *not* important to the actual question, yet *add* some code to make it a full repro of your actual scenario / attempt at doing what it is you think you need/want to do. Remember: we don't have any context, *all* we have is the text in your question.

Comment: why you want to remove $.getJSON . are you looking to remove `save` & `Get` from viewmodel and keep it somewhere outside ?

Comment: I don't entirely know if I am asking the right question.  I need a jumping off point so I can get started correctly.  Edited the question to hopefully add clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `ko.subscribable` for that and if you do then checkout [ko.postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox), a utility wrapper for `ko.subscriable`. This will allow you to **publish** your json across view models.

So using `ko.postbox`, you will **publish** and **subscribe** to events/topics. Make a separate function for loading your JSON from server, and make this publish an event and all your subscribers of that event will know whenever the data is received.

```
function DataLoader(){
  var self = this;
  self.loadJSON = function(){
    //Load JSON using getJSON from server and publish event "JsonDataLoaded"
    setTimeout(function(){
          ko.postbox.publish("JsonDataLoaded", data);
    }, 3000)
  };
}

var loader = new DataLoader();
loader.loadJSON();
```

So whenever you need new data, you will call `loader.loadJSON' and upon success, that will yield event/topic 'JsonDataLoaded`. You can then subscribe to this event in your view models. Something like

```
function ApplesViewModel(data) {
  var self = this;

  ko.postbox.subscribe("JsonDataLoaded", function(newData){
    ko.mapping.fromJS(newData,{},self);
  },self,true);

}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/dandy/pen/gazxmz?editors=101) reference.

Comment: It will take me a day or so to understand this...  

A couple questions: why the setTimeout - for demonstration or it is necessary? 

If I have a <textarea data-bind="value: ko.toJSON(fruit)">, can the updates to all the viewmodels also update one Json file?

Comment: yes, setTimeout for demonstration, simulating a getJson reponse. Not sure what you mean by `also update one Json file`? Are you referring to saving back to same json file? if yes, what to save and when will you save?

Comment: Example, if user edits a value in applesViewModel, and then user edits a value in bananasViewModel, will both updates be reflected in the same copy of the Json?  I don't need to actually save to server.  I just need to update the master-Json client-side.

Comment: With the above approach, the edits will be local to each view models and wont reflect in the master-json file.

Comment: Thank you, I understand from your answer that I will be better off putting everything into one view model, which should save me many days of trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Let me create a starting point for further conversation:

```
function ApplesViewModel(data) {
    self.slides = ko.observableArray($.map(data, function(item) { return new Slide(item) }));
    // setup other properties here 
}

function getFruitViewModel(modelUrl, targetModelHolder) {
    $.getJSON(modelUrl, function(allData) {
        targetModelHolder(new ApplesViewModel(allData));
    });    
}

function saveFruitViewModel(saveModelUrl, targetModelHolder) {
    $.ajax(saveModelUrl, {
        data: ko.toJSON(ko.unwrap(targetModelHolder)),
        type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(result) { alert(result) }
    });
}
```

Usage example:

```
    var applesViewModel = ko.observable();
    getFruitViewModel("json/masterJson.json", applesViewModel);
    // some work with view model(s)
    saveFruitViewModel("/masterJson", applesViewModel);
```

Please correct me in case of my misunderstanding.

#### Update 1

Creator function:

```
function getFruitViewModel(modelUrl, targetModelHolder, creator) {
    $.getJSON(modelUrl, function(allData) {
        targetModelHolder(creator(allData));
    });    
}
```

Usage:

```
    getFruitViewModel("json/masterJson.json", applesViewModel, function(data) { return new ApplesViewModel(data); });
```

Comment: Hi again TSV, I think the answer is that I should use one viewModel per each Json file in which I want to store my information.  Sound right?    Off topic: I posted a new question based on our other conversation, about Knockout templating, if you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390862/knockout-binding-external-template-files

Comment: @JenniferMichelle Yes, I thought if fruits models are the same you can use one class for describing each sort of fruits. If models are different you also can use "getFruitViewModel", but you should pass a creator function (Update 1).