# Knockout: Binding external template files

Tags: knockout.js

Based on these questions:

- [KnockoutJS: Using 'html' binding, new elements not binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756686/knockoutjs-using-html-binding-new-elements-not-binding/)
- [knockout js foreach binding is not updating when used in custom element (components.register)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167757/knockout-js-foreach-binding-is-not-updating-when-used-in-custom-element-compone/)

I have been testing several methods for importing html fragments to use as templates, but so far have no success on binding Knockout updates to them.  I am hoping for another example so I can understand better.

```
ko.components.register('my-slideshow', {
    template: { element: 'my-slideshow' },
    viewModel: ViewModel
});

ko.components.register('ko-slideshow', {
    viewModel: ViewModel,
    template: { require: 'text!caro.html' }
});
```

In the first component, when the html is already present, everything works correctly.  In the second component, the exact same html will load the correct information on init, but cannot be updated.

**Here's Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uecaj7a2/1/**

(I did not know how to create external html file for the Fiddle, but it has the rest.  This is my first Knockout project.)

Comment: You need `require.js` or custom AMD loader for loading external templates. Are you using any of them?

Comment: Yes, I added require.js, and everything loads fine using both methods.  The only difference is that the 2nd one does not update.  ... For example, updating via textInput or adding a new item does not have any effect on 2nd method of loading template.  I suspect it has to do with needing  applyBindingsToDescendants.  I copied a snippet with that code into the fiddle, but don't know how to activate it.

Comment: I wonder if it's a case of `applyBindings` being called before the template is loaded? Doesn't seem like that should happen.

Comment: @JenniferMichelle: I've prepared a sample - how to load knockoutjs components via requirejs - https://github.com/tsv2013/ko-requirejs-sample. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's quite useful for learning Require, thanks!  I think the issue arises when you move your button.  If it is not placed inside the imported html, but elsewhere in the page, then it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @JenniferMichelle: The described behavior is expected: the button is bound to the component's model internal function ("Onclick") and will not work outside the component scope. If you want to put the button in to another place, you should change the object and component models.